# Missing sequence number problem solved with XOR

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, binary

I'm trying to understand how the XOR operation managed to solve the problem  [PermMissingElem](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/perm_missing_elem/)

I know one of the properties of XOR is that:

```
A ⊕ B = C
C ⊕ A = B
C ⊕ B = A
```

```
>>> 3 ^ 4
7
>>> 7 ^ 3
4
```

This can be repeated for any number of operations, in this case it was 2 numbers, but it could be 3, 4, 5... n

Another property is that:

```
A ⊕ A = 0
A ⊕ 0 = A
```

```
>>> 3 ^ 3
0
>>> 3 ^ 0
3
```

But looking at the problem [PermMissingElem](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/perm_missing_elem/)
how was it possible to guarantee that the last operation would be exactly the number that was missing? Is there any literature on this algorithm, has anyone talked about it?

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11]

missing_element = len(A)+1

for idx,value in enumerate(A):

    print(missing_element, value, (idx+1), ' = ', missing_element ^ value ^ (idx+1))
    missing_element = missing_element ^ value ^ (idx+1)
```

out

```
11 1 1  =  11
11 2 2  =  11
11 3 3  =  11
11 4 4  =  11
11 5 5  =  11
> 11 7 6  =  10
10 8 7  =  5
5  9 8  =  4
4 10 9  =  7
> 7 11 10 =  6
```

as can be seen:

```
11 ⊕ 7 ⊕ 6 = 10
7 ⊕ 11 ⊕ 10 = 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XOR of the positive integers `[1...(N+1)]` is some constant:

```
C = 1 ⊕ 2 ⊕ ... ⊕ N ⊕ (N+1)
```

We can XOR both sides by the missing value, `M`:

```
C ⊕ M = (1 ⊕ 2 ⊕ ... ⊕ N ⊕ (N+1)) ⊕ M
```

Then we can rewrite the RHS in terms of the array `A`:

```
C ⊕ M = A[0] ⊕ A[1] ⊕ ... ⊕ A[N-1]
```

Finally, we can XOR both sides by `C` to get:

```
M = (A[0] ⊕ A[1] ⊕ ... ⊕ A[N-1]) ⊕ (1 ⊕ 2 ⊕ ... ⊕ N ⊕ (N+1))
```

Or rearranging,

```
M = ((A[0] ⊕ 1) ⊕ (A[1] ⊕ 2) ⊕ ... ⊕ (A[N-1] ⊕ N)) ⊕ (N+1)
```

Note that `+` could have been used instead of XOR for this solution (just need to be careful to avoid int overflow).